# Spring RSocket Security JWT Access Denied Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, rsocket

I am trying to use Spring Boot RSocket with Security using JWT Tokens. It is giving me an Access Denied error with no other useful information to help debug with?

> Access Denied.
> ApplicationErrorException (0x201): Access Denied  at
> app//io.rsocket.exceptions.Exceptions.from(Exceptions.java:76)    at
> app//io.rsocket.core.RSocketRequester.handleFrame(RSocketRequester.java:261)
> at
> app//io.rsocket.core.RSocketRequester.handleIncomingFrames(RSocketRequester.java:211)
> at
> app//reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160)
> at
> app//io.rsocket.core.ClientServerInputMultiplexer$InternalDuplexConnection.onNext(ClientServerInputMultiplexer.java:248)
> at
> app//io.rsocket.core.ClientServerInputMultiplexer.onNext(ClientServerInputMultiplexer.java:129)
> at
> app//io.rsocket.core.ClientServerInputMultiplexer.onNext(ClientServerInputMultiplexer.java:48)
> at
> app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
> at
> app//reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:364)
> at
> app//reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:404)
> at
> app//reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:725)
> at
> app//reactor.netty.http.client.WebsocketClientOperations.onInboundNext(WebsocketClientOperations.java:161)
> at
> app//reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at
> app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
> at
> app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
> at
> app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
> at app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
> at
> app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
> at
> app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at
> app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base@11.0.14/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

**Security Config** file

```
@Configuration
@EnableRSocketSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun authorization(rsocketSecurity: RSocketSecurity): PayloadSocketAcceptorInterceptor {
        val security: RSocketSecurity =
            rsocketSecurity.authorizePayload { authorize: RSocketSecurity.AuthorizePayloadsSpec ->
                authorize
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .anyExchange().permitAll()
            }
                .jwt { jwtSpec ->
                    jwtSpec.authenticationManager(jwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(jwtDecoder()))
                }
        return security.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtDecoder(): ReactiveJwtDecoder {
        return TokenUtils.jwtAccessTokenDecoder()
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(decoder: ReactiveJwtDecoder): JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager {
        val converter = JwtAuthenticationConverter()
        val authoritiesConverter = JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter()
        authoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_")
        converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(authoritiesConverter)
        val manager = JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(decoder)
        manager.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(converter))
        return manager
    }

    @Bean
    fun rsocketMessageHandler() = RSocketMessageHandler() .apply {
        argumentResolverConfigurer.addCustomResolver(AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver())
        routeMatcher = PathPatternRouteMatcher()
        rSocketStrategies = rsocketStrategies()
    }

    @Bean
    fun rsocketStrategies() = RSocketStrategies.builder()
        .routeMatcher(PathPatternRouteMatcher())
        .build()
}
```

**Message Controller** file

```
@MessageMapping("api.v1.messages")
@Controller
class MessageController {

    @MessageMapping("stream")
    suspend fun receive(
        @Payload inboundMessages: Flow<String>,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal jwt: String
    ) {
        println("MessageController: jwt: $jwt")
        println("MessageController: inbound message: " + inboundMessages.first())
    }
}
```

Testing using **MessageControllerTest** file

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class MessageControllerTest(
    @Autowired val rsocketBuilder: RSocketRequester.Builder,
    @LocalServerPort val serverPort: Int
) {

    @ExperimentalTime
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    fun `test that messages API streams latest messages`() {
        val admin = HelloUser(userId = "9527", password = "password", role = HelloRole.ADMIN)

        val token: UserToken = TokenUtils.generateAccessToken(admin)!!

        val authenticationMimeType: MimeType =
            MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_AUTHENTICATION.string)

        runBlocking {
            val rSocketRequester = rsocketBuilder.websocket(URI("ws://localhost:${serverPort}/rsocket"))

            launch {

                rSocketRequester.route("api.v1.messages.stream")
                    .metadata(token.token!!, authenticationMimeType)
                    .dataWithType(flow {
                        emit(
                            "Hey from test class"
                        )
                    })
                    .retrieveFlow<Void>()
                    .collect()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've add the rest of the code example I did to GitHub https://github.com/CJMobileApps/rsocket-jwt-security-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. RSocket currently has a bug or just bad documentation. The MimeType for JWTs `BearerTokenMetadata.BEARER_AUTHENTICATION_MIME_TYPE` says that it is deprecated and to use `MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_AUTHENTICATION.string)` instead, however that does not work.

When passing tokens continue using/use `BearerTokenMetadata.BEARER_AUTHENTICATION_MIME_TYPE` along with the token string.

```
.metadata(token.token!!, BearerTokenMetadata.BEARER_AUTHENTICATION_MIME_TYPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

*BearerTokenMetadata.BEARER_AUTHENTICATION_MIME_TYPE* is indeed deprecated and you should stop using it.

Code from *org.springframework.security.config.annotation.rsocket.RSocketSecurity*

```
protected List<AuthenticationPayloadInterceptor> build() {
            ReactiveAuthenticationManager manager = getAuthenticationManager();
            AuthenticationPayloadInterceptor legacy = new AuthenticationPayloadInterceptor(manager);
            legacy.setAuthenticationConverter(new BearerPayloadExchangeConverter());
            legacy.setOrder(PayloadInterceptorOrder.AUTHENTICATION.getOrder());
            AuthenticationPayloadInterceptor standard = new AuthenticationPayloadInterceptor(manager);
            standard.setAuthenticationConverter(new AuthenticationPayloadExchangeConverter());
            standard.setOrder(PayloadInterceptorOrder.AUTHENTICATION.getOrder());
            return Arrays.asList(standard, legacy);
        }
```

as you can see, even in code it is marked as legacy and used second.

instead of using deprecated thing you can modify your rSocketRequester. Bean configuration can look like:

```
    @Bean
    fun getRsocketRequester(strategies: RSocketStrategies): RSocketRequester {

        val authenticationMimeType =
            MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_AUTHENTICATION.string)

        //build you bearer token
        val bearerMetadata = BearerTokenMetadata(token)

        // add bearer encoder so you will be able to build auth header properly
        val extendedStrategies = strategies.mutate().encoder(BearerTokenAuthenticationEncoder()).build()

        return RSocketRequester.builder()
            .rsocketConnector { rSocketConnector: RSocketConnector ->
                rSocketConnector.reconnect(
                    Retry.fixedDelay(
                        2,
                        Duration.ofSeconds(2)
                    )
                )
            }
            // pass updated strategy to rsocket builder
            .rsocketStrategies(extendedStrategies)
            // pass your bearer token with up-to-date auth mime type
            .setupMetadata(bearerMetadata, authenticationMimeType)
            .websocket(URI.create("ws://localhost:8090/rsocket"))
    }
```